# WxWidgets || Taking a variable from another class

Tags: c++, class, wxwidgets

I've created simple complex calculator, now I need the Obliczenia class to support mathematical operations using methods.

How i can take variable from Zad2Frame to class Obliczenia?

```
class Obliczenia{
    void dodaj(){
        Zespolona przycisk1_1;
    Zespolona przycisk1_2;
    int wynik1;
    int wynik2;
    char* znak;
    wxString wynik;

    if(TextCtrl1->GetValue().ToDouble(&przycisk1_1.rzeczywista) && TextCtrl2->GetValue().ToDouble(&przycisk1_1.urojona)
            && TextCtrl3->GetValue().ToDouble(&przycisk1_2.rzeczywista) && TextCtrl4->GetValue().ToDouble(&przycisk1_2.urojona))
    {
        wynik1 = (przycisk1_1.rzeczywista + przycisk1_2.rzeczywista);
        wynik2 = (przycisk1_1.urojona + przycisk1_2.urojona);
        if(wynik2>=0)
        {
            znak="+";
        }
        wynik << wynik1<<znak<<wynik2<<"i";
        TextCtrl5->SetValue(wynik);
    }
    };
};
void Zad2Frame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    dodaj();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an accessor function for example:

```
int Zad2Frame::GetMyVariableValue()
{
    return myVariable;
}
```

or

```
void Zad2Frame::SetMyVariableValue(int newValue)
{
   myVariable = newValue;
}
```

These functions must follow `public:` where they are declared. Alternatively you could precede myVariable with `public:`. But directly exposing a variable prevents changing the behavior later. For instance in the future you may want:

```
void Zad2Frame::SetMyVariableValue(int newValue)
{
    myVariable = newValue;
    isMyVariableValid = true;
}
```